# Required Field Validator is not working before postback

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, validation

My problem seems very strange but I'm not finding the proper solution.
In my application I have some asp textboxes and also required field validators. Along with that I have a button.
My intention is to perform the page validation before form submit. But when I click on the button the requiredfieldvalidator is not showing any error. Instead the page is submitting to server.

Following is my aspx page code:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPhysicalTherapyTherapist1"  CssClass="txt-field"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator19" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPhysicalTherapyTherapist1"
ErrorMessage="this is required" ForeColor="Red"
ValidationGroup="PhysTherapyAdd" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPhysicalTherapyFrequency1"  CssClass="txt-field"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator18" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPhysicalTherapyFrequency1"
ErrorMessage="Frequency is required" ForeColor="Red"
ValidationGroup="PhysTherapyAdd" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:Button ValidationGroup="PhysTherapyAdd" ID="btn_physicaltherapy"
runat="server" Style="width: 80px;" CssClass="tabs" CausesValidation="false" Text="Save"
OnClick="btn_physicaltherapy_Click" />
```

I had put a local JavaScript as follows:

```
function validatePage() {
   if (Page_ClientValidate()) {
   alert("Valid Page");
    return true;
    }
    else {
    alert("Not a valid Page");
    return false;
    }
}
```

But When I click on the button keeping my text boxes empty, it's submitting the form to server.

Please provide me the proper solution.

Comment: From where you are trying to call validatePage() function?

Comment: You need to set CauseValidation  property to true on the submit button, this will mean the page needs to be validate before posting to the server.

Comment: Even if I put the CauseValidation to True it's not working... and I am calling validatePage() function OnClientClick event. But No USE.

Comment: Looking at your Save button, I don't see where you're calling OnClientClick event, I expect to see something like OnClientClick="if (Page_ClientValidate() == false) return(false);"

Comment: No @Bayeni it's not working even after putting that OnClientClick event in button.

Answer (score 2):

You button has `CausesValidation="false"` this will prevent any validation of the form. Try setting it to `CausesValidation="true"`

Or you can just remove it altogether, as it should default to true.

Generally speaking you should only set this to false if your are not trying to submit your page, for example if you have a `Save` function which will save a partially completed form, or if you are using an `<asp:UpdatePanel>` to retrieve data asynchronously

Comment: this was suggested under comments, 5 min ago :)

Comment: True, but I had started typing before I saw it

Comment: @Bayeni - You could have posted that as an answer in that case ;)

Answer (score 1):

Let the following 2 approaches:

**First Approach**: Using javascript to trigger validation, the following code work

```
<asp:Button ValidationGroup="PhysTherapyAdd" ID="btn_physicaltherapy"
runat="server" Style="width: 80px;" CssClass="tabs" CausesValidation="false" Text="Save" OnClick="btn_physicaltherapy_Click" OnClientClick="if (validatePage() == false) return(false);"/>
```

**Second Approach:** using code behind, on the btn_physicaltherapy_Click event put the following before processing your data

```
Page.Validate("PhysTherapyAdd");
if(!Page.IsValid) return;
```